# Python (other language also okay) library for drawing schematic diagram

Tags: library, python, diagram

I wondering how the eda tools (such as Verdi, Vivado) draws block diagram in such a nice manner.

See the figure below, the blocks are aligned in an ordered way. Also, all lines are horizontal or vertical

[image: fig]

I saw there are some libraries for drawing flow diagram or circuit diagram. But seems their aims are different from mine.
Bassically, I want a library that enable me to:

1. add block with customized-anchors
2. register connections between anchors

Then, it automatically place these blocks and lines in a "beautiful" way.
Is it possible?